# PHP 3rd level multidimensional array filter

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a 3 level multidimensional array

```
Array (
//first element
[7d69562076b7c92d82abd4333ee13ef9] =>
Array ( [unique_key] => 23f740a5eced0146558773804eab9f7a
[thwepof_options] => Array (
[order_date] => Array (
[name] => order_date
[value] => 05-02-2018, monday
[label] => Order Date [options] => ) )
[key] => 7d69562076b7c92d82abd4333ee13ef9
[product_id] => 528
[variation_id] => 616
[variation] => Array ( )
[quantity] => 1  ) )
//second element
[d9c2651b57c8b352502d908cbc69fb81] =>
Array ( [unique_key] => e6ed57f68d1f4613a502db45a0abaa59
[thwepof_options] => Array (
[order_date] => Array (
[name] => order_date
[value] => 06-02-2018, tuesday
[label] => Order Date [options] => ) )
[key] => d9c2651b57c8b352502d908cbc69fb81
[product_id] => 528
[variation_id] => 767 
[variation] => Array ( )
[quantity] => 1 ) ) )
```

I have an `$order_date_value` variable which value is

> 06-02-2018, tuesday

or later

> 05-02-2018, monday

etc.

So it's dinamic. I would like to remove those elements from the array where `[thwepof_options][value]=>` isn't equal with my `$order_date_value`.

Like if my value is tuesday, then remove the second element and keep the first element.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php). Within your callback function you could then determine whether or not the value should stay in the array.

Comment: Is it works on so complex array like this? If yes how could possible find those values?